# Insert an image inside a rectangle drawn by Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to insert an image instead of the blue rectangle drawn by Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,741); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 741

%Shape: Rectangle [id:dp7318361349835825]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 3; green, 42; blue, 90 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (49,100) -- (597,100) -- (597,631) -- (49,631) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6003532783152192]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (192,502) .. controls (192,492.06) and (200.06,484) .. (210,484) -- (341,484) .. controls (350.94,484) and (359,492.06) .. (359,502) -- (359,614) .. controls (359,623.94) and (350.94,632) .. (341,632) -- (210,632) .. controls (200.06,632) and (192,623.94) .. (192,614) -- cycle ;
%Rounded Rect [id:dp6087048165722606]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 255; green, 255; blue, 255 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (186,112) .. controls (186,104.76) and (191.87,98.9) .. (199.1,98.9) -- (445.9,98.9) .. controls (453.13,98.9) and (459,104.76) .. (459,112) -- (459,191.8) .. controls (459,199.03) and (453.13,204.9) .. (445.9,204.9) -- (199.1,204.9) .. controls (191.87,204.9) and (186,199.03) .. (186,191.8) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (265,553) node [xslant=-0.02] [align=left] {\textbf{{\LARGE \textcolor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}{XXX} }}\\[0.5em]\textbf{{\LARGE \textcolor[rgb]{0.7,0,0} {XXX}}}\\[0.5em]\textbf{{\LARGE \textcolor[rgb]{0.7,0,0} {XXX}}}\\\\\textcolor[rgb]{0.9,0,0} {XXX}};
\end{tikzpicture} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome. (2) You should never use a generator for not-too-complicated figures, please read the manual and write the code yourself. (3) I think you already get what you want, as I can see an image there.

Comment: Are you looking for `\draw (329,147) node[draw]  {\includegraphics[width=157.5pt,height=55.5pt]{Logo.png}};`? I.e. add `[draw]` to the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\stackinset` of the `stackengine` package to overlay stuff, including `tikz` pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=6pt
\stackinset{r}{}{c}{}{\scalebox{.35}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node (A) at (-12,-2)  {N5xx};
            \node (B) at (-10,4)   {N612};
            \node (C) at (-5,7)    {N614};
            \node (D) at (0,4)     {N624};
            \node (E) at (2,-2)    {N7070};
            \node (F) at (-1,-8)   {N7071};
            \node (G) at (-9,-8)   {Others};
        \end{scope}
%
        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);
            \path [->] (A) edge[loop left = 25, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
%
            \path [->] (B) edge[loop left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);
%
            \path [->] (C) edge[green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 30, green,very thick]   node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (C) edge[loop above = 15, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 30, green,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (C) edge[ green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}   (G);
%
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (D) edge[loop right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (G);
%
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25, purple!50 ,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[loop right = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);
%
             \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25, very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 15, very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[loop right = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);
%
        \end{scope}
%
        \end{tikzpicture}}%
}{%
\stackinset{c}{-2.5cm}{b}{}{\colorbox{white}{\parbox{80pt}{\bfseries\LARGE
  \color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} XXX \\[0.2em] XXX\\[0.2em] XXX\\\\\normalsize
  \mdseries\textcolor[rgb]{0.9,0,0} {XXX}}}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{}{\includegraphics[width=157.5pt,height=55.5pt]{example-image}}
{\includegraphics[width=13cm,height=13cm]{example-image-a}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me. However the image is not centered. I need it to be centerd and i wanna add some text on it

Comment: @Imade *Which* image is not centered?  One of the insets, or the large background image?

Comment: the large background image is not centered

Comment: @Imade It is set just like a letter of text (i.e., in horizontal mode).  Thus, you can enclose the whole thing in `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, or use `{\centering...\par}`.

Comment: It works great. How obout adding a text in the center of the large background image @StevenBSegletes

Comment: @Imade `\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{<inset>}{<background>}`